# Header in listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have the listview and i need add a header like this:

```
ID   Start   End   Place
-------------------------
```

This is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Cestovni_prikazy";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}",
                 ((int)reader["id"]), ((string)reader["PocatekCesty"]),
                 ((string)reader["KonecCesty"]), 
                 ((string)reader["MistoJednani"])));
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to add a header..

Comment: Use a table as layout template & define your header inside <th> tags

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In C#? It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add four columns to your `listView` like this:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Start", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("End", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Place", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

And don't forget to change View property:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

And you should change your while loop like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = (string) reader["id"];
    item.SubItems.Add((string) reader["PocatekCesty"]);
    item.SubItems.Add((string) reader["KonecCesty"]);
    item.SubItems.Add((string) reader["MistoJednani"]);

    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but now i have all loaded data under ID.....and under Start,End and Place isnt nothing...